# reject these foreign characters ū ų š ą ė ž į ę č in regexp

Tags: regex, posix

As the title says I am simply trying to come up with the regexp that would reject the following foreign characters ū ų š ą ė ž į ę č but just cannot seem to succeed. The ones I tried below look of course awkward and most importantly they do not work. Would appreciate any help / comments / advices at all. Many thanks!

```
/^[[:alpha:]\s]+/u/ 

/^[ū ų š ą ė ž į ę č]+/

/^[[:alpha:]\s]+/u$/ 

/^[ū ų š ą ė ž į ę č]+$/
```

=== UPDATE. ===

Here is the regexp that works in my case, I worked it out by testing. That is any of these characters that are present anywhere in the word with any symbols in front of these characters and after them as well.

```
/^.*č|ę|ė|į|š|ų.*$/
```

However, now it triggers OK only on the š character, all the others fail for some reason. Any further comments anyone, please? Thanks!

=== UPDATE 2. ===

I was wrong. It fails on š too. I have the regexp now, but it boils down to correct charset and stuff I reckon..

=== UPDATE 3. ===

echo $LANG returns:

```
en_US.UTF-8
```

locale charmap retuns:

```
UTF-8
```

locale -a returns:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf-8
POSIX
```

Comment: Have you tried your filter/expression with regular English characters to see if it works?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Yep, it's working fine with regular English characters.

Comment: If those characters are mapped to extended character set you may want to search against that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970327/regular-expression-to-restrict-extended-ascii-character-set

Comment: In which tools are you going to use the regexs? With GNU `grep` (2.16)  and `sed` (4.2.2) the following commands work as expected: `grep '[ūųšąėžįęč]'`, `grep '[[:alpha:]]'` and `sed 's/[ūųšąėžįęč]/X/g'`. ...but my locale contains `.UTF-8`. If yours does not you must specify it like `LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8 grep --color=yes '[[:alpha:]]'`.

Comment: The locale's encoding and the file's character encoding must agree. If you save a file with an encoding of UTF-8, but your system uses ISO-8859-7, you're going to have issues because those characters will be encoded as 2 bytes (or more). This issue also becomes complex when you consider that the characters may be given in their decomposed form if using UTF-8 or another Unicode character encoding for the file, meaning `ū` is `\u0075\u0304` (encoded as UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32). Of course, that should be a rare case, but I still wonder why you want to filter these characters specifically...

Comment: Interesting comment, Chrono, thanks. I will try to double-check on those. These are the characters that are normally used in spam that targets my system, that's why I thought I would reject any words that contain any of these characters

Comment: In text files (not binary ones) handled by the current software you will rarely meet encodings different than ISO-8859-1/ASCII and Unicode UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you pabouk for your input. I will think about it all and try to test it (if I come up how to do it). I am on UTF-8 that's for sure. Testing it further on i found one interesting thing. I tried separating the characters and it works OK just on š, all the others seem to fail. This is the rule used: /^.*č|ę|ė|į|š|ų.*$/ Does it help any one to suggest where to look now?

Comment: my system is UTF-8 as it says in my question and my file --mime-encoding filename is unkown-8bit. Is that what causes the issue Chrono?

Comment: With 8-bit character sets, the best you can do is guess. If a character `č` is encoded using Windows-1257 for example, it is represented by the 8-bit character code `\xE8`. That is also the character `è` encoded using ISO-8859-1 and `Þ` in IBM code page 850. Apparently [`file` doesn't understand Windows code pages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1730878/1730914#comment28119889_1730914), and some versions of `file` [don't understand files encoded using one of the ISO 8859 encodings](http://superuser.com/a/301552/351658#comment387061_351658) either. In both cases, you'll see "unknown-8bit".

Comment: Instead of using `file`, try one of the alternatives listed in the answers to the questions linked.

Comment: Hey Chrono! Thank you for your further advice! However, it doesn't appear to be the problem I believe. I easily converted my file into UTF-8, luckily it takes just literally a second to do so. Now my system is UTF-8 and my files are UTF-8 but nonetheless despite the fact that it matches now in charset which in turn also complies with your theory it still does not work. I mean it cannot see these foreign characters. Meanwhile I went for another regexp on entire encoding and it works OK for the time being. Although I hope this solution is only temporary because it blocks a bit more than expected

Comment: On second thoughts this entire encoding blocking provides even more spam protection from all sorts of mail robots and scripts so I may leave it like that. Human beings will easily follow my simple rule to put it in English. All the rest such as automatized senders, cron jobs, mailing lists, etc., and those who do not understand English will be blocked and that is exactly what I am after. This solution is in testing for now, I closely monitor what is being blocked but the goal is reached even though it may not be as perfect with a bit broader implementation and slightly awkward.